# Select element 100% width bug if option with long text is selected (Select2 bootstrap theme)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I am using select2 with bootstrap 3 theme and the select2 element overflow container if option with long text is selected and width of element is 100%.

This happens only in Mozilla Firefox!!

I create an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jf3n2ycd/2/)

```
.select2-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

This is the code which affect on element overflow

```
span.select2-selection__rendered {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I think this might be a known issue, but I don't have Firefox right now to test it. Does the overflow issue still happen if you remove the Bootstrap theme and just use the default?

Comment: Yes it does. For now I resolved with templateSelection but it is not the right way.

Answer (score 33):

Set inline style:

```
<select class="select2" style="width:100%">
```

Comment .select2-container extra css:

```
/*.select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}*/
```

Add 'element' width on select2 init:

```
$('.select2').select2({
     width: 'element',
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
  });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/chemark/z9sLqLbx/

If you are using bootstrap try [this](https://www.itread01.com/p/668131.html) solution instead, adapted from a post on github:

```css
.form-group .select2-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

If you’re using an input-group instead of a form-group, then change the first line to this:

```
.input-group .select2-container {
```

Answer (score 14):

This works for me, using select2 together with bootstrap 4:

```
.select2-container{ width: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are use bootstrap then it works.

```
.form-group > .select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your main CSS file

```
.select2-container{ width: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in jQuery:

```js
$('.select2-container').css("width","100%");
```